# Add or Remove Tabs based on Switch position

Tags: java, android, android-tablayout, fragmentstatepageradapter

I want to add or remove a fragment from the tab based on switch position

if switch is on then the fragment will be added if switch is off then the tab will be removed

here is the code i did in the main activity this actually works but only when the app is retstared and get the details from the Sharred Prefrence

MainActivity.java

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout);
            viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

            mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings = getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFS_NAME_NSFW, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            boolean rewardGranted = mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false);
            viewPagerAdapter = new FragmentViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), getLifecycle(), rewardGranted);
            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);
            new TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, viewPager, (tab, position) -> {
                // Set the tab titles using switch-case
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        tab.setText("Meme");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        tab.setText("Art");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        if (rewardGranted) {
                            tab.setText("NSFW");
                        } else {
                            tab.setText("Settings");
                        }
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        tab.setText("Settings");
                        break;
                }
            }).attach();
```

FragmentStateAdapter

```
 public FragmentViewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle,boolean rewardGranted) {
        super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        fragmentList.add(new MemeFragment());
        fragmentList.add(new ArtFragment());
        if (rewardGranted) {
            fragmentList.add(new NsfwFragment());
        }
        fragmentList.add(new SettingsFragment());
    }

@NonNull
@Override
public Fragment createFragment(int position) {
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}


/**
 * Return the number of views available.
 */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return fragmentList.size();
}
public Fragment getFragment(int position) {
    // Retrieve the fragment at the specified position
    return fragmentList.get(position);
}
```

and here is the Switch code which currently just adding the sharedprefrence

SettingsFragment.java

```
nsfwSetting.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings.edit();
                editor.putBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, isChecked);
                editor.apply();
            }
        });
        nsfwSetting.setChecked(mSharedPrefs_nsfw_settings.getBoolean(REWARD_GRANTED_KEY, false));
```

Comment: The current behaviour is expected. However there are multiple ways to handle this. You could use `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener`, a `LiveData` via a shared `ViewModel` approach or a callback approach from Fragment to Activity but I wouldn't suggest this.

Comment: Does anyone get what the problem is in this question?